# Displaying based on condition

Tags: ios, iphone, xib

I have two Views In viewController. I dont want to use two xib file for them. I want to use them in single xib. Now I want to dispaly view based on condition. For example if , if condition is correct then I want to display 1st view otherwise second. I dont know how to do this?

I am adding second view by this way but it is not displaying:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"service-provider"] boolValue]==1){
    [[MyAppDelegate.tabBar.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setTitle:@"History"];
    self.title = @"History";
    self.view.hidden=YES;
    self.ServiceProviderView.hidden=NO;
    [self.ServiceProviderView addSubview:historyTable];
}
else{
    [[MyAppDelegate.tabBar.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setTitle:@"Search"];
    self.title = @"Search";
    self.view.hidden=NO;
    self.ServiceProviderView.hidden=YES;
    [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    searchLbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:GZFont size:18.0f];
    headingLbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Garamond 3 SC" size:20.0f];
    NSMutableAttributedString *gpsSearch = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"GPS Search"];
    [gpsSearch addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName
                      value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle]
                      range:(NSRange){0,[gpsSearch length]}];
    self.headingLbl.attributedText = gpsSearch;
    self.headingLbl.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    btn_Favorite.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:GZFont size:18.0f];
    btn_inviteUser.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:GZFont size:18.0f];
    btn_locateNearBy.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:GZFont size:18.0f];
    btn_scanBarCode.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:GZFont size:18.0f];
    txtSearchUsername.font=[UIFont fontWithName:GZFont size:15.0f];
    txtSearchEstablishment.font=[UIFont fontWithName:GZFont size:15.0f];
}
}
```

Here if first condition satisfied then serviceProviderView is not displaying.I have added this view in xib.

Comment: if (correct) {
    [viewOne setHidden:NO];
    [viewTwo setHidden:YES];
} else {
    [viewOne setHidden:YES];
    [viewTwo setHidden:NO];
}

Comment: make sure you of taking 2 view and all the objects related to those view and are subview accordingly. then if condition is true set view2.alpha=0.0f;
view1.alpha=10.0f; and viseversa

Answer (score 0):

Create Referencing IBOutlets for those two views. Use those reference to hide or display them.

```
if(<condition>)
{
   firstView.hidden = YES;
}
else
{
   secondView.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: Means When vieedidLoad called I check for condition and based on that I display view???

Comment: Yes, you can do this in viewDidLoad.

Comment: I have viewController already with one view having named view. So now I need to add one view having name view1...and then in viewdidload check which one I want to to display??...I want to display them as my main view..means in current session secondview never be displayed.